# Invalid character in apache tomcat 7 rolename

Tags: apache, authentication, tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to use fully distinguished names in role names for `Apache tomcat`.  The role name will include `"=" chars`.

**For example:**

```
    <tomcat-users>
            <role rolename="cn=tomcat,dc=com"/>
            <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="cn=tomcat,dc=com"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

**When I try to start tomcat I get:**

> SEVERE: Exception creating UserDatabase MBeans for UserDatabase
>   javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException: Invalid character '='
>   in value part of property
>           at javax.management.ObjectName.construct(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.management.ObjectName.(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createObjectName(MBeanUtils.java:870)
>           at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanUtils.createMBean(MBeanUtils.java:379)
>           at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:194)
>           at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.createMBeans(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:112)
>           at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent(GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener.java:84)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:401)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:346)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:725)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:675)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:451)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to configure Tomcat to use LDAP authentication use the JNDIRealm:

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html#JNDIRealm